# SQL: Selecting rows from non unique column values once partitioned by another column

Tags: sql

Using SQL here. Trying to select all rows where the column value is unique within that specific partition.

Have tried:

```
 select * 
   from dataTable 
  where value in ( select value 
                     from dataTable 
                    group by tv_id, value 
                   having count(*) > 1)
```

but it returns the full table-- i think the issue is that the values for many of tv_ids are identical and overlap.

What I have:

`tv_id          value
  1               1
  1               2
  1               2
  1               3
  2               1
  2               1
  2               2
  2               3
  2               4
  3               1
  3               1
  3               2`

What I want:

`tv_id          value
  1               2
  1               2
  2               1
  2               1
  3               1
  3               1`

I have a bunch of tv_ids and essentially, I only want the rows where the value is not unique within each tv_id.
Ex: I don't want tv_id, value: 3, 2 because it is the only combination in the data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this does the trick

**Oracle Option**

I include this oracle version because it enables you to understand better what are you querying.

```
select tv_id, value  
from dataTable
where (tv_id, value)  in (
  select tv_id, value
  from dataTable
  group by tv_id, value
  having count(1) > 1
)
```

**SQL**

But this is a standard sql version that will work with almost any database engine

```
select tv_id, value  
from dataTable d1
  join (
    select tv_id, value
    from dataTable
    group by tv_id, value
    having count(1) > 1
  ) d2
  on d1.tv_id=d2.tv_id
 and d1.value=d2.value
```

You need to query the same table twice because the `group by` makes a `distinct` in your data, so you won't retrieve duplicated rows as you show in your expected output.